# How can I make minimum JQuery UI Tabs control?

Tags: jquery-ui

I only need a JQuery UI Tabs, so I access http://jqueryui.com/download and only select Core, Widget and Tabs 3 check boxs, then download the package jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.zip

I find that there are many files I needn't in the package, but I don't know how can I delete these files.

And more css\ui-lightness\jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css inculde many content I don't need if I only use Tabs, it seems that I can delete the whole folder css\ui-lightness\images and don't cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://jqueryui.com/download and select core, widget and tabs then download the package.

This is almost the minimum requirement. You only need files which in the js and css folder.

If you remove css\ui-lightness\images when you page using ui-lightness theme you will found that there is little difference between the brightness of the tab labels.

Of course. If you did not using ui-icon, you can remove ui-icons_*.png and rules ui-icon-* on jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css